# Dynamic gradient not getting applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<style>
  .normal_gradient {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                                 from(#ccc), to(#000));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
                  startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
    color:#fff
  }
</style>

<div class='normal_gradient'>foo</div>
<div class='dynamic_gradient'>bar</div>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$('.dynamic_gradient').css({
  background: ('-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,' +
                               'from(#ccc), to(#000));')})
</script>
```

The normal gradient gets applied, but the dynamically set one doesn't.  Why not?  Running this in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon at the end should not be there for JavaScript.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/nChhf/

Instead of this:

```
$('.dynamic_gradient').css({
  background: ('-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,' +
                               'from(#ccc), to(#000));')})
```

Do this:

```
$('.dynamic_gradient').css({
  background: ('-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,' +
                               'from(#ccc), to(#000))')})
```

Or the exact same thing but formatted more nicely (and without the concatenation):

```
$('.dynamic_gradient').css({
    background: '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000))'
})
```

Comment: Yes semi colon does need to be removed. Reading the questions again, He may have not meant dynamically added content. I removed my post